# Choose between Interface Implementations with spring applicationContext?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, jdbc, phpmyadmin

I'm using Eclipse Juno IDE and phpMyAdmin.

I have java application, for this application I created a DB in phpMyAdmin. 
Now, I have an interface for the DB methods.. 
Lets say the interface is like that:

```
public interface DBInterface{
  public Vector<Employees> getAllEmplyess();
  public void addNewEmployee(int ID, String name,String department);
}
```

Now I need to implements this interface in two ways:

1) JPA

2) JDBC

Lets say that I implemented the interface in the two ways mentioned above.

How can I choose between the with the spring mechanism in the applicationContext.xml file?
How does it work?

Comment: You cant make jdbc as an interface-implementation, but you can create an interface-implementation jdbc-based.

Comment: I know that jpa is depends on JDBC, but my lecturer wants those two implementations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you need both JPA and JDBC implementations (JPA is based on JDBC)?

The way to distinguish between the two is to create 2 separate DAO classes (both implement your interface)

```
public class JDBCDao implements DBInterface {...}
public class JPADao implements DBInterface {...}
```

and inject an appropriate DAO bean in spring xml (application-context file) when needed.

For example the application context xml will look something like: 
(`dao` member of the EmployeeService class is of type `DBInterface`)

```
<bean id="JPADAO" class="com.yourpackage.JPADao".../>
<bean id="JDBCDAO" class="com.yourpackage.JDBCDao".../>

<bean id="EmployeeService" class ....>
    <property name="dao" ref="JDBCDAO" />
    ...
</bean>
```

or alternatively you can inject the DAO in code.

```
ApplicationContext ctx = AppContext.getApplicationContext();  
EmployeeService svc = (EmployeeService) ctx.getBean("EmployeeService");  
DBInterface dao = (DBInterface) ctx.getBean("JPADAO");
svc.setDao(dao);
```

Comment: thanks aviad, I know that jpa is based on JDBC but my lecturer wants those two implementations

Comment: Why consider both ? maybe because writing a plan JDBC solution can often be much faster and simpler. All depends on the model, and then the developer using the right tool for the job. JPA is not the right tool for every persistence job (and indeed is not based on JDBC when considering other types of datastores).

Comment: hi aviad, when i'm trying to get the JPA bean as you write in the code, i'm getting an exception that says that the jpa provider isn't defined.. so do i need to include the persistence file in the applicationContext file?

Comment: sure. you need it available on the class-path so spring could configure JPA. take a look on this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132565/spring-jpa-and-persistence-xml or just google for examples of configuring JPA in spring.

Answer (score 1):

*Aside the fact JPA depends on JDBC ....*

If you want to control it though the **ApplicationContext** XML file the easiest way is to simply define the implementation of your choice. Say you have two implementations

```
 public class JpaDB implements DBInterface { ... }
 public class JdbcDB implements DBInterface { ... }
```

and a service which expects a `DBInterface`, say

```
 public class Service {
     private DBInterface db;

     public void setDBInterface(DBInterface db) {
        this.db = db;
     }
 }
```

Then your spring configuration file could look something like

```
...
<bean id="service" class="com.company.service">
    <!-- Select either "jpa" or "jdbc" depending on preference -->
    <property name="dbInterface" ref="jpa"/> 
</bean>

<bean id="jpa" class="com.company.JpaDB"/>
<bean id="jdbc" class="com.company.JpaDB"/>
```

Comment: hi Johan, when i'm trying to get the JPA bean as you write in the code, i'm getting an exception that says that the jpa provider isn't defined.. so do i need to include the persistence file in the applicationContext file?

Comment: @eliorsh, http://www.baeldung.com/2011/12/13/the-persistence-layer-with-spring-3-1-and-jpa/