# JPA - persistence.xml out of jar-file

Tags: java, xml, jpa, application-resource

Can I put my `persistence.xml` in any folder on my hard-drive and can access to it with my Java SE application?

Is there any solutions for my problem?

Comment: I prefer keeping it with the program. That ensures that they are always in sync with each other. What is the reason you want to put it somewhere else?

Comment: *"Is there any solutions for my problem?"*  What 'problem'?

Comment: If you really know what you are doing, you can using a datasource without persistence.xml file. The datasource file can be a simple properties file on the disk. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132565/spring-jpa-and-persistence-xml.

Answer (score 0):

*persistence.xml* must be present **under META-INF in the CLASSPATH** of the running application. That is the only restriction. You could easily enough include some other location in the CLASSPATH and have your *persistence.xml* there as long as it was in a folder META-INF.

Some JPA providers allow you to just specify the location as a persistence property, doing away with the META-INF requirement, but then that is not covered by the JPA spec so not portable