# Cannot find the declaration of element 'persistence, but have xmlns set up correctly

Tags: java, jpa, persistence

This is driving me insane.

I have an appContext-model.xml file which imports persistence.xml.

```
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/persistence.xml" />
```

My persistence.xml is set up with the correct xmlns details as far as I am aware for EclipseLink 2.5.1 (i.e. JPA 2.0).

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" 
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence 
        http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">

        <persistence-unit name="graps-jpa" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">        
            <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>                
            <class>com.mycompany.rd.model.graps.PrProject</class>       
            <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>        
            <properties>            
                <property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="Oracle"/>            
                <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="none"/>            
                <property name="eclipselink.weaving" value="static"/>        
            </properties>
        </persistence-unit>  

        <persistence-unit name="xp-jpa" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">        
            <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>                
            <class>com.mycompany.rd.model.misf.Project</class>      
            <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>        
            <properties>            
                <property name="eclipselink.target-database" value="SQLServer"/>            
                <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="none"/>            
                <property name="eclipselink.weaving" value="static"/>        
            </properties>
        </persistence-unit>
    </persistence>
```

And my pom loads in:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
            <version>${eclipselink.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>commonj.sdo</artifactId>
                    <groupId>commonj.sdo</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
```

where version is 2.5.1.

I tried adding javax.persistence to pom.xml, and none of these seem to help:

```
<!-- 
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.persistence</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.0</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
         -->

        <!-- 
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
                <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
                <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
            </dependency>

         -->
```

But I keep getting this:

```
cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'persistence'.
```

8 hours wrestling with this....any help appreciated.

i

Comment: You don't need to import the persistence in a spring xml file, see [this](https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/)

Comment: not sure I understand.  I have 2 entity manager factories, and want to place them in a separate persistence.xml file (to avoid apparent issues with having multiple EMs).  I dont want to move to JavaConfig at the moment.

Comment: No, the error is that spring don't undestand your persistence.xml, remove the `<import resource="classpath:META-INF/persistence.xml" />`, the `persistence.xml` is not a valid Spring XML config.

Comment: thanks, but how do i define my 2 persistent units?  I have had problems setting this up and it seems to be a solution to have a separate persistence.xml file.

Comment: removing the import and using this instead seems to work:<bean id="pum"
  class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager">
  <property name="persistenceXmlLocations">
   <list>
    <value>classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml</value>
   </list>
  </property>
 </bean>

Comment: You see the difference?. The bean is a spring tag.

Comment: Yes, thanks....you made me very happy.  Post it as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `persistence.xml` file is not part of spring, so you need to remove:

```
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/persistence.xml" />
```

And create a `Spring bean` with receive the `persistence.xml` and handle it:

```
<bean id="pum" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManag‌​er">
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocations"> 
        <list> 
            <value>classpath*:META-INF/persistence.xml</value> 
        </list> 
    </property>         
</bean>
```

Also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132565/spring-jpa-and-persistence-xml)